# How do we import the jbpm-playground into jbpm Workbench?

Tags: git, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I have started my server with '**`Dorg.kie.demo=false`**', because I have firewall blocking.

I have downloaded `jbpm-playground` and `uf-playground` examples separately. But how do I import that into `jbpm` - console workbench?

I tried downloading them and placing them directly to the .niogit folder. But it is not working.

Any other way of importing the projects into workbench?

Answer (score 1):

You can import any git repo in the UI (through Administration -> Clone repository).  This could be an online repo but also a local one.  If you're able to import the jbpm-playground repo from github to some file system, zip it up and extract it on your local system, you should be able to import it using a url like file://{path_to_folder}/jbpm-playground/.git

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can clone the bare repo by accessing the repo via ssh and then push those two examples using git commands